# Convert enum to string digit

Tags: c#, enums

I want to convert `enum` to `string` with three digits in C#.

Like this:

```cs
enum test : short
{
    asdf, qwer, zxcv
}

test t = test.qwer;

string result = t.ToString("%03D") // Is this right?
```

I want to print `001`

Comment: why do you never accept answers? It can be useful for others in the future and it gives points to you and he who helped you

Answer (score 4):

In a normal enumeration you can just cast as an integer, then call "ToString" with a format specified. In your case that should look like:

```
test t = test.qwer;
string result = ((int)t).ToString("000");
```

That should do it! Good luck.